# td:first-child does not seem to work in IE

Tags: html, css

I'm new to HTML and i'm just trying to make a basic table where I can specify the width of columns in the CSS.

I am creating an HTML set of Accounts (35 page document) so tables are the basis of what I need to produce and there will be about 5 standard tables used throughout the html.

I have had a quick go and the code below seemed to be exactly as I needed however the td:first-child does not work in IE.

I have searched and it is supported.  Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong?  Also if there is a better way of doing this let me know.

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Company Accounts</title>
    <style type="text/css">
        table { width: 264mm; border: 1px solid; table-layout:fixed}
        td {border: 1px solid; padding: 5px}

        .T1C1 td:first-child {width: 10mm; text-align:right}
        .T1C2 td:first-child + td {width: 50mm}
        .T1C3 td:first-child + td + td {width: 10mm; text-align:right}
        .T1C4 td:first-child + td + td + td {width: 50mm; text-align:right}
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <table class="T1C1 T1C2 T1C3 T1C4">
        <tr> <td>1</td> <td>2</td>  <td>3</td>  <td>4</td> </tr>
        <tr> <td>1</td> <td>2</td>  <td>3</td>  <td>4</td> </tr>
        <tr> <td>1</td> <td>2</td>  <td>3</td>  <td>4</td> </tr>
        <tr> <td>1</td> <td>2</td>  <td>3</td>  <td>4</td> </tr>
        <tr> <td>1</td> <td>2</td>  <td>3</td>  <td>4</td> </tr>
    </table>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: IE9, both chrome and firefox work fine

Comment: Fixed, needed to add a document type

Answer (score 2):

The `:first-child` pseudo-class is one of the many CSS features that are not supported by IE in [Quirks Mode](http://www.cs.tut.fi/~jkorpela/quirks-mode.html). This is why adding a doctype helped, as mentioned in comments. But it’s not just any doctype. It needs to be one that triggers “Standards Mode” in IE, such as `<!doctype html>`, to be placed at the very start of the HTML document.

This particular quirk is explicitly described in Microsoft documentation:
“Note   Pseudo-class enabled only in standards-compliant mode (strict !DOCTYPE).”
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/cc848865%28v=vs.85%29.aspx
The word “strict” in the document is misleading, however, and in addition to the doctypes listed on the linked page
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ms535242%28v=vs.85%29.aspx
the HTML5 doctype `<!doctype html>` works too,

Answer (score 0):

Here is the refference for this css pseudo-class : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/:first-child

You can find there the browser compatibility table.

There are some warnings for IE at the bottom of the page :

> Internet Explorer 7 doesn't update the styles when elements are added dynamically. In Internet Explorer 8, if an element is inserted dynamically by clicking on a link the first-child style isn't applied until the link loses focus.